# ¿Como insertar fecha en SQL server con C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

tengo esta tabla en SQL Server

[image: Tabla eleccion]

Y tengo este código de C#

```
public class conexion{
SqlConnection data = new SqlConnection("Data Source = source; Initial Catalog=base; Integrated Security = True");
SqlCommand solicitud = new SqlCommand();
public void Insertar(string nombre, string fechaV, string fechaC)
{
    try
    {
        //solicitud.CommandText = "INSERT INTO eleccion (nombre, fechaVotacion, fechaCreacion ) VALUES ('" + nombre + "', " + DateTime.Parse(fechaV) + "," + DateTime.Parse(fechaC) + ");";
        solicitud.CommandText = "INSERT INTO eleccion (nombre, fechaVotacion, fechaCreacion ) VALUES ('" + nombre + "', 24/01/2023, 24/01/2023);";
        solicitud.Connection = data;
        data.Open();
        solicitud.ExecuteNonQuery();
        data.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex){ MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex);}
}}
```

El problema es que el INSERT que esta comentado me arroja un error de sintaxis, mientras que el segundo INSERT si ingresa el nombre. También, cuando se ingresan los datos, independientemente de si lo hago con el programa o directo en la consola de SQL server, no guarda la fecha correctamente. Por ejemplo si ingreso lo siguiente.

```
INSERT INTO eleccion (nombre, fechaVotacion, fechaCreacion ) VALUES ('nombre', 2023/01/24, 24/01/2023);
```

Lo que se guarda en la tabla es:

[nombre] [1900-03-26 00:00:00:000] [1900-01-01 00:00:00:000]

Comment: No es lo que guarda en la tabla. Es lo que recupera una select de la columna para una row. Pero las fechas se guardan en binario, no en texto. Además es un error bastante común y bastante peligroso, concatenar strings a una sentencia, que sirven para tener SQL Inyection. Debes de usar un SqlParameter para pasarle la fecha.  Y las sentencias de inserción con fecha llevarían apóstrofes. Busca SqlParameter

Comment: La sentencia con los strings podría ser así: `solicitud.CommandText = "SET DATEFORMAT DMY; INSERT INTO eleccion (nombre, fechaVotacion, fechaCreacion ) VALUES ('" + nombre + "', '24/01/2023', '24/01/2023');";`. Set dateformat te permite establecer un formato para la sentencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la forma que lo estas haciendo te va a generar error a parte de que es inseguro por las inyecciones SQL. Por mi parte recomendaría que lo hicieras de esta forma:

```
string _connectionString = "Data Source = source; Initial Catalog=base; Integrated Security = True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
     {
         string solicitud = "INSERT INTO eleccion (nombre, fechaVotacion, fechaCreacion) VALUES (@nombre, @fechaVotacion, @fechaCreacion)";

         using (SqlCommand data = new SqlCommand(solicitud, connection))
            {
               data.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre);
               data.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaVotacion", Convert.ToDateTime(fechaV));
               data.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fechaCreacion", Convert.ToDateTime(fechaC));

               connection.Open();
               int result = data.ExecuteNonQuery();

               // Check Error
               if (result < 0)
                   MessageBox.Show("Los datos no se pudieron guardar");
               else
                   MessageBox.Show("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
             }
      }
```